# Eclipse RCP: what does the percent symbol mean?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I have seen it a couple of times that in the plugin.xml labels or other string values have a leading `%` symbol. Like in:

```xml
<command
    commandId="org.eclipse.ui.examples.contributions.item2"
    icon="icons/editor.gif"
    id="contributions.trimItem"
    label="%Trim.item"
    tooltip="%TrimItem.toolTip">
</command>
```

in [this example](https://github.com/vogella/eclipse.platform.ui/blob/master/examples/org.eclipse.ui.examples.contributions/plugin.xml).

What does the percent symbol mean? Is it a reference of some kind? If a string value is referenced by it, where is it defined?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It means the value for the label or tooltip is actually in a `plugin.properties` or `OSGI-INFO/i10n/bundle.properties` file. The value following the % is a property key to look up in that file.

So with '%Trim.item' there will be a line:

```
Trim.item=the trim label
```

in the properties file.

This is used to allow the text to be internationalized since Eclipse will look for national language versions of the properties files.

plugin.properties is used if there is a entry `Bundle-Localization: plugin` in the MANIFEST.MF for the plugin, if there is no Bundle-Localization entry OSGI-INFO/i10n/bundle.properties is used.

If you right click on a plugin.xml (or other files) you can choose 'Plug-in Tools > Externalize Strings...' to start a tool which will convert plugin.xml and MANIFEST.MF strings to this format.

The plugin.xml / MANIFEST.MF editor can generate warnings when you use strings which have not be 'externalized' like this.

Comment: Note that the name of the `.properties` file is dictated by the value of the `Bundle-Localization` entry. The conventional value is `plugin` but it can be any name you want. For example, setting `Bundle-Localization: foo` would cause OSGi to look up properties in a file named `foo.properties`.

Comment: My RCP application just got a bit more awesome :)

Comment: If you want to do internationalization in your Java there is a separate mechanism for that http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseInternationalization/article.html

Comment: Is there a way to escape the `%` character if you need the actual value to start with it?

Comment: To answer my own question - I've tried using `&#37;` (gets interepretted as % for replacement still), `&amp;#37;` (in case the double jeopardy works as in escaping escape characters in regex in Java), `\%`, `^%` and `\u0025` - all of which get inserted as their literal text values as entered. UPDATE (in case anyone else is looking for it ever) - `%%` appears to work - the `plugin.xml` syntax highlighter still things it's a placeholder but the first one is elided and the second remains as desired